# Gradle Error configurations.add String cannot be cast to Configuration

Tags: gradle

My gradle file says

```
configurations.add "externalDeps"
```

If I run gradle with 1.4 I don't have a problem.

If I run gradle with 2.0 I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration
    at org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration$Namer.determineName(Configuration.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectCollection$add$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at build_3p9qdtholqj79o8rnevdt3d7t0.run(D:\Code\trunk\projects\build.gradle:6)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 82 more
```

What has changed that is causing this error?

How should I be defining this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The manual](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:configurations) explains how to create a configuration:

```
configurations {
    externalDeps
}
```

The [DSL documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer.html) shows that the configuration container has a method create():

```
configurations.create('externalDeps')
```

The [API doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html) for the class shows that all its add() methods take a Configuration as argument, hence the exception you get.